# Cheap Video Editor to insert an image into a video

Tags: video, images, video-editing

I have an mp4 video file, and all I want to do is to display an image over the original video. A good example of what I'm trying to do is the black censor bars that they use in movies, or the ads that come up at the bottom of TV shows.

Anyone know any reasonably priced/free video editing software that can do this? Windows or Ubuntu programs welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[Openshot](http://www.openshot.org) should do what you require and has windows or linux based versions.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Make sure you check out the [Answer Quality Guidlines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/133)